# Changing page labels (clistview, cgridview) witout changing pager css (bootstrap)

Tags: php, yii

When I set 'pager' in CGridView it change bootstrap look, I try with cssFile to null or false, it doesn't work.

```
        'pager' => array(
            'class' => 'CLinkPager',
            'firstPageLabel' => '<<',
            'prevPageLabel' => 'smthprev',
            'nextPageLabel' => 'smthnext',
            'lastPageLabel' => '>>',
        ),
```

Comment: when you say bootstrap, do you mean the [bootstrap extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap)?

Comment: @bool.dev yes, I only have to remove yiiPager class. I found one solution with jQuery $('.yiiPager').removeClass('yiiPager') , but if there is something better, I have many forms.

Comment: @bool.dev it isn't good solution because when I go to next page I again have yiiPager class.

Comment: i'm not sure, can you try : `'lastPageLabel'=>'>>','htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'') ..` . i.e add the htmlOptions to the end of the pager array, plus shouldn't the class be also BootPager instead of CLinkPager ?

Comment: @bool.dev YES IT IS! Thanks :) If you want write this like answer, and I will mark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap extension checks if htmlOptions['class'] is set , i.e : isset($htmlOptions['class']), so if we set empty class, then it should work. So add this:

```
    'pager' => array(
        // rest of code
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'')
    ),
```

Comment: btw, did you change the class also?

Comment: so, lemme get this clear, you tried with htmlOptions only and it doesn't work? or did it work with only htmlOptions, and didn't work with class?

Comment: sorry if you didn't undestand me :). It works with htmlOptions, but i tried later with BootPager and it doesn't work.